# htaccess rule per host with RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess

i would like to use the following rule in my htaccess to forward one url to another but it won’t work. Could anybody help me?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule /cms-page.html http://www.mydomain.com/second-cms-page.html [L,R=301]
```

the following rule is working, but it would forward the whole domain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/second-cms-page.html [L,R=301]
```

and i can’t use “RedirectPermanent” because there i can’t specify a host. This is necessary because there are multiple domains accessing the same htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading slash from your regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms-page\.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/second-cms-page.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.